# How do you match depth of already installed trim?

Tags: wood, tools, trim

One of the harder things I have come across when buying houses is making some of the poor craftsmanship, look at least OK.  One of the things that keep popping up is when floor trim (and actually this house here has exterior trim work with same issue) does not match up.  It has 6 inch trim and they met this trim in the corners with a taller trim that presumably should be the same depth - I understand that some stick out for effect but this isn't it.

So I have a piece of trim about 1/16 deeper than the piece right next to it.  It looks like they had sanded it down in the past and added some spackle to smooth out the transition but that wore off I guess.

Is this something that I just have to sand down?  Is there some that works faster or better?  I thought about using a planer but not sure how well I would do with a 2 inch planer and 6 inch piece.

Comment: Could you post a pix?

Comment: @bib - will get at least one example tonight.